# Google Cloud Messaging for synchronizing folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api, dropbox, google-cloud-messaging, data-sharing

I'm trying to develop an App whose purpose is to share files in my smartphone with some friends, kind of Dropbox. I have a FileObserver watching a directory and when any change is applyed to one of its files, the App should read and do some stuff with it, write the result in another different folder and upload it to a server in order for my friends to get them when they sync in their smartphones using, obviously, the same App.

I've been taking a look at Dropbox API but I think it's not possible to programme something like that, I don't know with Google Drive.

The thing is, I've come across Google Cloud Messaging and wondering if this could be the solution I'm looking for.

So I'd like to know if this is possible with GCM and how it could be done. If you know another way to do so it'll be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is pretty much the whole point of the Dropbox API. :-) What specifically did you have trouble with? Perhaps you can share the code you've written so far.

Comment: I haven't written anything so far, just taken a look at Dropbox API to find out if it's possible so and ask at the forum. Didn't you tell me it wasn't possible to create "programatically" a shared folder with some partners with Dropbox API?

Comment: This is correct. I didn't understand from your question here that you were trying to programmatically share a folder.

Comment: One question: if I'm using the Sync API, all the files I'm creating are automatically synced, when online, to my App Folder if I've understood well... so I guess I can't share that folder with "my friends". 

I suppose that the API i need to use is the Core API, isn't it?

Comment: App folders can't be shared, unfortunately. You could either use "File type" permissions with the Sync API (if you can restrict your app to certain file types), or you can use the Core API.